# LWC deploy fails without errors

Tags: lightning-web-components, code-coverage

I'm getting a test coverage warning, but not an error. Is the warning the reason why the deploy fails on production? Worked in the sandbox.

```
sf project deploy start -o foo@example.com
Deploying v59.0 metadata to foo@example.com using the v59.0 SOAP API.
Deploy ID: 0AfQx0000007361KAA
Status: Failed | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 2/2 Components (Errors:0) | 20/20 Tests (Errors:0)

Test Results Summary
Passing: 20
Failing: 0
Total: 20
Time: 31244
 ›   Warning: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 74%, at least 75% test coverage is required.
```

Running the deprecated command `sfdx force:source:deploy` gives the error `Unable to determine the username of the org to delete`:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -o foo@example.com
Warning: We plan to deprecate this command in the future. Try using the "project deploy start" command instead.
Error (1): Unable to determine the username of the org to delete. Specify the username with the --target-org | -u flag.
```

Although a google search for that error produces zero results. And I am not trying to delete an org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing one of the methods in my Apex class resolved the issue which means I'm within the 75% testing coverage. So besides it being a warning and not an error, it must have been the reason for the deploy failing.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying to production, 75% coverage is required. For other orgs, no code coverage is required. A deploy to production that fails to meet the code coverage requirements will fail. See [Testing and Code Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm).

Comment: So it should be an error and not a warning. That is what confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little pluggin a while ago to dig into fine details of code coverage calculations during deployments, probably it will help https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/lazy-for-salesforce-deplo/agiglidkkgindpamdcbboahbbkihbgge

Answer (score 0):

Yes code coverage is the issue, while deploying from sandbox to sandbox there is no need of code coverage, while you are deploying it to Production so 75% code coverage is at least needed.